# Violación de segmento

Tags: c, archivo

```
int bwrite (unsigned int nbloque, const void *buf){
  lseek( descriptor,nbloque*BLOCKSIZE , SEEK_SET);
  int x = write(descriptor,buf, BLOCKSIZE);

  if(x== -1){
    printf("Error al escribir");
  }
}
```

Este es el código el cual se encarga de la escritura de el fichero que ya crea perfectamente (y con permisos) otro método.

Al intentar llenarlo de bloques de un tamaño concreto, vease:

```
for( a = 0; a < atoi(argv[2]); a = a + 1 ) {
  bwrite(a,buf);
}
```

Donde `argv[2]` corresponde a un número `int`, me da el error:

> Violación de segmento (`core' generado) c

Al ejecutar el programa (compila bien).

Soy bastante principiante en c, y he programado en java algo, de ahí mi problema con punteros y tal (he buscado sobre el error y he encontrado algunos hilos sobre que puede provocarlo, aunque no consigo ver en mi código el fallo).

EDIT: MAIN:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
 void *buf;

memset(buf,0,BLOCKSIZE);
bmount(argv[1]);
int a;
for( a = 0; a < atoi(argv[2]); a = a + 1 ){
      bwrite(a,buf);
   }

bumount();

}
```

¿Alguien me puede decir donde falla mi programa para que me de ese error?

Comment: Una pregunta sencilla, cómo corres el ejecutable?

Comment: primero compilo con

 gcc -o ejecutable ejecutable.c otroarchivo.c

Y ejecuto con

 ./ejecutable nombre numero  (2 argumentos que necesita el ejecutable)

Comment: He editado el post y añadido el main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void *buf; // 1

memset(buf,0,BLOCKSIZE); // 2
```

Donde:

1. Puntero no inicializado que apunta a una región aleatoria de la memoria (y que muy seguramente no te pertenece
2. Inicializas la memoria apuntada por el puntero del punto 1

En este punto pueden suceder dos cosas:

1. Sobreescribes memoria que no te pertenece, con lo que el sistema operativo o algunas aplicaciones se vuelven erráticas
2. El Sistema Operativo detecta el acceso a memoria y mata tu aplicación para impedir que suceda lo comentado en el punto 1.

La solución pasa por hacer una reserva de memoria:

```
void* buf = malloc(sizeof(BLOCKSIZE));
```

Aunque te puedes ahorrar la llamada a `memset` cambiando `malloc` por `calloc`:

```
void* buf = calloc(BLOCKSIZE,sizeof(void));
```

Por supuesto nunca está de más acordarse de liberar la reserva de memoria cuando ya no es necesaria:

```
free(buf);
```

Comment: Me ganaste por 1 segundo :P

Comment: @NaCl te entiendo perfectamente... PaulaPlusPlus me lo suele hacer muy a menudo

Comment: mi_mkfs: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
Abortado (`core' generado)

Parece que sigue habiendo problemas con punteros y memoria, he leido sobre el problema y dicen que es por memoria corrupta en algún sitio, aunque sigo sin ver donde(auque tu respuesta ha arreglado el otro problema, gracias)

Comment: @flaixman `BLOCKSIZE` va a indicar el tamaño de la reserva en bytes (tal y como está el código) si de repente necesitas más memoria de la que has reservado vas a tener el mismo problema... vas a tener que poner un ejemplo mínimo, completo y que verifique el problema si quieres respuestas más precisas

Comment: Era un problema con el memset, lo he quitado y he cambiado a calloc. Parece que el problema se ha ido y se ejecuta el programa (aunque el tamaño del Disco donde escribe sigue a 0).

Comment: @flaixman esa es otra pregunta diferente que merece una respuesta totalmente distinta... además ya te adelanto que con el contenido de la pregunta actual sería imposible responder al por qué de ese problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas. Creo que a partir de aqui me las puedo apañar solo (ya que entiendo donde puede haber el problema.

Muchas gracias.